# Один элемент пагинации перекрывает другой, что делать?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть парсер, в котором при переходе по элементу пагинации не меняется ссылка, попробовал написать цикл нажатия на элемент пагинации, но выбивает ошибку мол элемент не кликабельный потому что его перекрывает другой элемент

```
Message: Element <div id="goods_back" class="back_pagin"> is not clickable at point (674,566) because another element <a href="/led-tel-r-gazer-tv32-hs2-g/p71261031/"> obscures it
```

Так же не совсем понятно почему выводит только один товар со всей страницы, а не все.

Я так понимаю что просто сайт мусорный потому что бывает такое что тянет недействительный элемент со страницы (Грубо говоря всякий мусор)

В основном моя проблема, в которой я прошу вашей помощи заключается в том что бы помочь мне настроить переход по элементу пагинации, потому что вроде должно работать, но ничего подобного.

Вот код парсера:

```
print('Load:', url)
        driver.get(url)
        while True:
            
            
            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tile-container .goods-item .goods-item-content"):
                

                try:name = item_el.find_element_by_class_name('good-description').text
                except NoSuchElementException:name = ''

                # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_class_name('price-wrapper').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'

              #  try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('').text
               # except NoSuchElementException:
                #    nal = " "

                row = name, price, #nal
                print(row)
                items.append(row)
                try:
                    a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pages #goods_back')
                    a_next_page.click()

                except NoSuchElementException:
                    break
```

Вот ссылка на сайт, который я пытаюсь спарсить: https://eldorado.ua/search/?q=Gazer

Вот полный код, если кому-то понадобится: https://dpaste.org/N1JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Первая ваша проблема в том, что элемент пагинации определяется моментально, когда еще не прогрузился весь товар, в этот момент он находится на верху страницы(где потом появляется плитка с товаром, а он улетает вниз). Сделайте обычный ***time.sleep(2)*** перед входом в цикл например(незабудьте импортировать модуль time).
2. А проблема загрузки одного элемента в том, что вы в цикле перебора товаров переходите на след страницу на первой итерации, вам нужно переход по пагинации делать после завершения цикла, а не в нем(уберите лишние отсупы, чтоб он был в while но не в for)

Comment: Окей, это я сделал, а можете мне помочь с отступом в break? Потому что IDE его постоянно красным подсвечивает как бы я его не двигал. https://dpaste.org/jZJ2

Comment: И еще не совсем понятно почему цикл загружает постоянно первую страницу и ничего более

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII сейчас ваш break не в цикле снова в примере, ваш try с break [должен стоять на одном уровне с for](https://dpaste.org/dBbd#L3,5,10,15,28)

Comment: Спасибо, и последняя микропросьба, можете мне подсказать почему скрипт не видит кнопку? Пишет просто `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'` в 27 28 строке
https://dpaste.org/jZJ2#L27,28

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII Может оно только кидает ошибку в строке 28? зачем вам 2 раза подрят ее нажимать? возможно, когда вы нажимаете второй раз подряд не подождав загрузки страницы оно и кидает ошибку

Comment: Вполне вероятно, завтра уже буду проверять, спасибо за помощь!