# Проблема с элементом пагинации

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Помогите порешать с элементом пагинации, выбивает ошибку мол один элемент перекрывает другой, никак не пойму что с этим делать.

[Мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345698/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c) не подходит, потому что страница точно прогружается(Там в сумме задержка 5 секунд), и парсит все отлично до того как выбьет ошибку.

```
try:
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(3)
...
Тут парсер
...
try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination')
                a_next_page.click()
                time.sleep(2)
 
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Вот весь код парсера: https://dpaste.org/qcCX

Вот ссылка сайта, в котором что-то не так: https://atl.ua/search?q=Gazer

Это то как работает программа до ошибки: https://dpaste.org/o2ev, при том первые стрницы 3-4 перелистывает нормально

```
Traceback:  
Message: Element <div class="pagination"> is not clickable at point (833,617) because another element <div id="myoverlay" class="pp-visible"> obscures it
```

UPD:

Я понял что перекрывает элемент, при перелистывании страницы вылезает вот это вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно было бы это обойти?

UPD 2.0:

Я понял что вылазит больше элементов чем 1 при парсинге этого сайта, попытался обойти с помощью `try: except:`, ничего не вышло, сейчас финальный вариант обхода выглядит вот так:

```
Error_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]')
    Error_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div')
    Error_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]')
    try:
        while True:
...

тут парсер

...
if  Error_1.is_displayed():
                driver.implicitly_wait(10.5)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]').click()
            elif Error_2.is_displayed():
                 driver.implicitly_wait(10.5)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div').click()
            elif Error_3.is_displayed():
                 driver.implicitly_wait(10.5)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]').click()
            else: 
                continue

            try:
                
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination')
                a_next_page.click()
                time.sleep(3.5) 

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

И этот способ работает но слишком коряво, поэтому все еще нужна помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, я решил эту проблему, изначально выбивало ошибку по той причине что выскакивали всякие `div` блоки которые перекрывали элемент пагинации, главная задача была их очистить, как я это сделал:

Ввел переменные `div-ов`, которые нужно было убирать

```
 driver.get(url)
    Error_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]')
    Error_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div')
    Error_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]')
```

Ввел условие которое звучит так `если Error_1/2/3 - видно, драйвер кликает по close button`, выглядит оно вот так:

```
if  Error_1.is_displayed():
                time.sleep(15)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]').click()
            elif Error_2.is_displayed():
                 time.sleep(15)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div').click()
            elif Error_3.is_displayed():
                 time.sleep(15)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]').click()
```

Так же в конце этого условия я прописывал

```
else: continue
```

Это было супер неправильно, потому что как оказалось, `continue` не продолжает программу, он начинает следующий проход цикла, а значит в случае когда условия было под парсингом, скрипт не доходил до элемента пагинации, и на 4 странице я ловил постоянную прогрузку страниц, а когда условия было выше парсинга элементов, то скрипт просто завершался на 4 странице

Окончательный код парсера выглядит вот так:

```
driver.get(url)
    Error_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]')
    Error_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div')
    Error_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]')
    try:
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(2)
            if  Error_1.is_displayed():
                time.sleep(15)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="close_bubble"]').click()
            elif Error_2.is_displayed():
                 time.sleep(15)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pp-form"]/div').click()
            elif Error_3.is_displayed():
                 time.sleep(15)
                 driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bingc-active-close-button"]').click()
            
            
            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".col-cell-3.middle, .col-inline-xs-3.middle"):
                

                try:name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-title a').text
                except NoSuchElementException:name = ''

                # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-price').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'
                try: nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-status').text
                except: nal = 'Нет в наличии'
                
                    
                row = f'{DT.datetime.now():%H:%M_%d-%m-%Y}',name, price, nal
                print(row)
                items.append(row)

            

            try:
                
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination')
                a_next_page.click()
                time.sleep(1) 

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```